# How do you render content from a CMS with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, content-management-system, react-dom

My react app gets content from Wordpress. The editors can add content to WP's editor where they can style the text and format it.

How do I render this text on the client site with react?

So far I have tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but the name suggests to me that I shouldn't be using it - at least not very often, but all my content comes from Wordpress.

So is there another way of rendering HTML strings in react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, it is Reacts replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code can be a bit risky because you can inadvertently expose your users to XSS attacks (cross-site scripting).

You can set HTML directly from React, but you type the **dangerous*** in the name (and pass an object with a __html) to **remind yourself that it's dangerous**.

In your case, since the content comes from WP where authorized editors edit the content, it should be fine.